# Adding Bottle framework in existing python script

Tags: python-2.7, bluetooth, bottle

In my python script I am doing bluetooth and RF communication on individual threads respectively. I want to add Rest Web Method in same script using Bottle web framework.

If I add below code, in existing python script, it wont work. How to make it work in existing script.

```
from bottle import Bottle, run

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my system. Did you end up solving this? Pointing the browser to http://localhost:8080/hello shows "Hello World"

Comment: It works only when i put above code in separate file abd run it... But i want it to be part of another python script file... Then it won't work...

Answer (score 0):

What it does not work? The output `Hello world` on your browser? The bluetooth application?

Did you add the `run(app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug = True)` call in a separate thread (this function call will block)?

For example:

```
import threading
import time
from bottle import Bottle, run

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

class MyRestServer(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, app, host, port, debug):
        self.app = app
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.debug = debug
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.server = self.app.run(
                                host=self.host, 
                                port=self.port, 
                                debug=self.debug
                            )


s = MyRestServer(app=app, host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
s.start()

# Execution continues
print 'Rest server started'

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'Rest server running'
```

Replace the `while True:` part with the rest of your application.

Comment: Hi Mike, can you please share the sample code to call [ run(app, host='localhost', port=8080,debug=True)]  in separate thread.